# Why does the green container appear below the red container?

Tags: html, css, position

In this code, I think `div1` should be floating above `div2`.
Because div1 is applied `float:left` attribute. But the result is that `div2` is floating above `div1`. Why?

```css
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    font-size:0.7em;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
    float:left
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
    position:relative;
    left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green div1"></div>
<div class="red div2"></div>
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: actually, I didn't get your question properly. what do you want output?

Comment: You might get better results looking into flex

Comment: if you remove position:relative, the float will get on the top. It's all about the "painting order"

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I know that relative affects it, but I don't know what principle it is.. I'll search for the painting order you mentioned. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `float: left` style is used to justify an element to the left. For an element to render above or below another element, you must assign a `z-index` style; it appears above the other element with the higher `z-index` style.

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  font-size:0.7em;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;  /* This style has been added. */
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: -1; /* This style has been added. */
}
```

```html
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

---

###### References

- [MDN Web Docs - `float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)
- [MDN Web Docs - `z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: the first z-index you added has no effect because the element is not positioned, only z-index:-1 has an effect here

Comment: I purposely added it so that the post owner can understand the difference between the styles.

Comment: what "difference"? this can be misleading because z-index *alone* is not enough to identify the painting order